# SQL Server return a first valid join

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join

I have a view which should include product numbers from Table A (product, product_name, product_hierarchy, ...) and average production time from Table B (product, semi_product, average_time, ...).

Problem is, that there isn't record for every product in the second table.

So I have to match products with their production times where possible and for the rest use other methods:

1. Make a join based on first 7 product numbers (next numbers are only a variant)
2. Make a join of product number from Table A to semiproduct in Table B
3. Same as (2.) but again with first 7

I stored the data in Excel in the past and used some of formula combining IFERROR with VLOOKUP. The solution I found here doesn't work for me - makes a duplicate rows.:

```
FROM 
    table_a a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    table_b b ON CASE 
                    WHEN a.product = b.product THEN 1
                    WHEN LEFT(a.product, 7) = LEFT(b.product, 7) THEN 1
                    WHEN a.product = b.semi_product THEN 1
                    WHEN LEFT(a.product, 7) = LEFT(b.semi_product, 7) THEN 1
                    ELSE (some_calculation_based_on_columns_in_1st_table)
                 END = 1
```

Thanks very much for help in advance.

// According to **TABLE A** there should be only once line "AGK 10" to 2017-01-01 in result set...

[TableA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCMNm.jpg) - [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFIzV.jpg)

Comment: The "duplicate" rows probably have nothing to do with your join conditions but rather the underlying data.  That being said, you should show us your data.

Comment: show us some sample data and your expected result